# Where do you set the identityserver3 endpoint urls?

Tags: identityserver3

Are the urls for the endpoints in identityserver3 configurable?

How come in the example for MVC the Authority is set to:

```
https://localhost:44319/identity
```

While the standalone webhost (minimal) sample has the authorization endpoint set to:

```
https://localhost:44333/connect/authorization
```

Has something been configured somewhere so that the /identity will work. 
Or is the .../identity not the IDSrv3 endpoint at all, but rather only the API call instead of

```
https://localhost:44321/identity
```

which is what is called in the CallApiController...  (I would change this example totally to something else with different names, so that there's a clear difference between what is part of the app (Foo and Bar) and what is part of idsrv3 (auth claims tokens and scopes)  --sigh.

(end of question...)??

---

In any case:

When the webhost standalone minimal idsrv3 is down - I'm getting:

- No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ...  Wasn't sure what I was doing wrong, but was sure that I was doing something wrong. (Forgot to run the IDSrv3)
- When its up, in both paths: (/identity and /connect/authorization)
  I get 404 not found,
- and if I just give the root with a trailing slash, I get:  Error, The client application is unknown or is not authorized, instead of showing me the login page...

So it seems the trailing slash root is the correct way to go, which leaves me with my first question, so how/why is the Authority set in the MVC demo to include the path /identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer url is configured in the startup.cs file.
In the MVC app the IdS is configured under 'webroot'/identity. In The console app IdS is running under the root of the selfhost 'webroot/'

```
 app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
            {
                idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "Embedded IdentityServer",
                    SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

                    Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                                .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get()),

                    AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
                    }
                });
            });
```

The other urls you mentioned are all urls which can be resolved via the discovery document: http://'webroot'/.well-known/openid-configuration
or in case of the MVC app:  http://'webroot'/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: It turns out that the MVC demo mixes you up quite a lot, because the API call is called .../identity as well. Its just on a different port. 

I promised to volunteer and help make a clearer demo. Will do when I get some time.

Comment: I agree the demo is complex for a first start, I am still strungeling with all the client demos. Good luck!

Comment: I went through all of the tutorials in hopes of implementing my own solution.  I added a controller named Identity and mapped them to the URLs like so:      [Route("")] - added at class level.  I then returned a Redirect(../identity/) in the various methods of where I want to redirect users to.